# BrowserSync not working in Laradock (using laravel-mix)

Tags: debugging, browser-sync, laravel-mix, laradock

Using Docker Desktop w/WSL2 on Windows 10, Ubuntu 20.04 is the distro. Project is deployed locally using Laradock.

My project domain in my Windows `hosts` file is `mgkg.test`. (By default, Ubuntu is using the same `hosts` file as Windows; I assume it either copies or links to it.) With containers up and running (no other containers are running except the ones for this project), `http://mgkg.test` works just fine.

Here is my `webpack.mix.js` file (default comments have been removed; my current comments are retained):

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .sourceMaps()
    .browserSync({
        logLevel: "debug",
        notify: true, // For debugging
        open: false,
        /**
         * Proxy an EXISTING vhost. Browsersync will wrap your vhost
         * with a proxy URL to view your site.
         */
        // proxy: "mgkg.test", // test domain
        // proxy: "nginx" // Docker Compose Service name
        // proxy: "mgkg_nginx_1" // Docker container name
        proxy: {
            target: "http://mgkg.test" // Project URL
        }
    });
```

(As you can see, I've tried a number of different values for the `proxy` option; the output and results are all the same.)

When I run `npm run watch`, this is the output (with debugging turned on):

```
laradock@8ae999bf55c6:/var/www/mgkg$ npm run watch                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            > @ watch /var/www/mgkg                                                                                                                        > npm run development -- --watch                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             > @ development /var/www/mgkg                                                                                                                  > cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          10% building 1/1 modules 0 active                                                                                                              webpack is watching the files…                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                98% after emitting SizeLimitsPlugin                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            DONE  Compiled successfully in 4779ms                                                                                               5:57:51 PM                                                                                                                                               [debug] -> Starting Step: Finding an empty port                                                                                                       Asset      Size   Chunks             Chunk Names                                                                                        /css/app.css   178 KiB  /js/app  [emitted]  /js/app                                                                                              /js/app.js  2.91 MiB  /js/app  [emitted]  /js/app                                                                                            [debug] Found a free port: 3000                                                                                                                [debug] Setting Option: port - 3000                                                                                                            [debug] +  Step Complete: Finding an empty port                                                                                                [debug] -> Starting Step: Getting an extra port for Proxy
[debug] +  Step Complete: Getting an extra port for Proxy                                                                                      [debug] -> Starting Step: Checking online status                                                                                               [debug] Resolved www.google.com, setting online: true
[debug] Setting Option: online - true
[debug] +  Step Complete: Checking online status
[debug] -> Starting Step: Resolve user plugins from options
[debug] +  Step Complete: Resolve user plugins from options
[debug] -> Starting Step: Set Urls and other options that rely on port/online status
[debug] Setting multiple Options
[debug] +  Step Complete: Set Urls and other options that rely on port/online status
[debug] -> Starting Step: Setting Internal Events
[debug] +  Step Complete: Setting Internal Events
[debug] -> Starting Step: Setting file watchers
[debug] +  Step Complete: Setting file watchers
[debug] -> Starting Step: Merging middlewares from core + plugins
[debug] Setting Option: middleware - List []
[debug] +  Step Complete: Merging middlewares from core + plugins
[debug] -> Starting Step: Starting the Server
[debug] Proxy running, proxing: http://[whatever proxy is set to]
[debug] Running mode: PROXY
[debug] +  Step Complete: Starting the Server
[debug] -> Starting Step: Starting the HTTPS Tunnel
[debug] +  Step Complete: Starting the HTTPS Tunnel
[debug] -> Starting Step: Starting the web-socket server
[debug] Setting Option: clientEvents - List [ "scroll", "scroll:element", "input:text", "input:toggles", "form:submit", "form:reset", "click" ][debug] +  Step Complete: Starting the web-socket server
[debug] -> Starting Step: Starting the UI
[debug] Setting Option: session - 1605376671887
[UI] Starting Step: Setting default plugins
[UI] Step Complete: Setting default plugins
[UI] Starting Step: Finding a free port
[UI] Step Complete: Finding a free port
[UI] Starting Step: Setting options also relevant to UI from BS
[UI] Step Complete: Setting options also relevant to UI from BS
[UI] Starting Step: Setting available URLS for UI
[debug] Getting option via path: [ 'urls' ]
[UI] Step Complete: Setting available URLS for UI
[UI] Starting Step: Starting the Control Panel Server
[UI] Using port 3001
[UI] Step Complete: Starting the Control Panel Server
[UI] Starting Step: Add element events
[UI] Step Complete: Add element events
[UI] Starting Step: Registering default plugins
[UI] Step Complete: Registering default plugins
[UI] Starting Step: Add options setting event
[UI] Step Complete: Add options setting event
[debug] +  Step Complete: Starting the UI
[debug] -> Starting Step: Merge UI settings
[debug] Setting Option: urls - Map { "local": "http://localhost:3000", "external": "http://172.28.0.5:3000", "ui": "http://localhost:3001", "ui-external": "http://localhost:3001" }
[debug] +  Step Complete: Merge UI settings
[debug] -> Starting Step: Init user plugins
[debug] Setting Option: userPlugins -
[debug] +  Step Complete: Init user plugins
[Browsersync] Proxying: http://[whatever proxy is set to]
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 -----------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://172.28.0.5:3000
 -----------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://localhost:3001
 -----------------------------------
[Browsersync] Watching files...
```

Note that the `External` URL points to an IP address (instead of the test domain). That IP address is listed in the results of an `ifconfig` command run inside the `nginx` container:

```
bash-5.0# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:AC:1C:00:07  
          inet addr:172.28.0.7  Bcast:172.28.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:405 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:353 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:229638 (224.2 KiB)  TX bytes:131732 (128.6 KiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:AC:1B:00:03  
          inet addr:172.27.0.3  Bcast:172.27.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:18 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1396 (1.3 KiB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:129 (129.0 B)  TX bytes:129 (129.0 B)
```

However, the test site is not reachable in a browser using either of these 2 IP addresses; nor, does `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` work (with or without the BrowserSync port #3000). But the `http://localhost:3001` link DOES work to display the BrowserSync UI in the browser. Yet, clicking on any of the test site links in the BrowserSync UI always results in a 404 error (generated by nginx) or a `this site cannot be reached` (generated by the browser).

Can anyone explain:
- why the "naked" test URL works, but the proxied URL doesn't?
- why is BrowserSync substituting the IP address for the test domain?
- why the IP address doesn't work?
- how I can make this work correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get this working by adding in webpack.mix.js

```js
mix.browserSync({
    open: false,
    proxy: {
        target: "nginx", // replace with your web server container
        proxyReq: [
            function(proxyReq) {
                proxyReq.setHeader('HOST', 'mydomain.test'); // replace with your site host
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by adding the following
code in webpack.mix.js

```
mix.browserSync({
    open: false,
    proxy: {
        target: "nginx", // replace with your web server container
        proxyReq: [
            function(proxyReq) {
                proxyReq.setHeader('HOST', 'mydomain.test:3000'); // replace with your site host and port of BrowserSync
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

Note: It is important to set the port of the BrowserSync host.

```
proxyReq.setHeader('HOST', 'mydomain.test:3000');
```